# Adding two columns in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add two columns and create a new one. This new column should become the first column in the dataframe or the output csv file.

```
column_1 column_2
84       test
65       test
```

Output should be

```
column         column_1 column_2
trial_84_test   84      test
trial_65_test   65      test
```

I tried below given methods but they did not work:

```
sum = str(data['column_1']) + data['column_2']

data['column']=data.apply(lambda x:'%s_%s_%s' % ('trial' + data['column_1'] + data['column_2']),axis=1)
```

Help is surely appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Create sample data**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1': [84, 65], 'column_2': ['test', 'test']})
```

**Method 1**:  Use [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to create new column, and then reorder.

```
>>> df.assign(column=['trial_{}_{}'.format(*cols) for cols in df.values])[['column'] + df.columns.tolist()]
          column  column_1 column_2
0  trial_84_test        84     test
1  trial_65_test        65     test
```

**Method 2**:  Create a new series and then [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

```
s = pd.Series(['trial_{}_{}'.format(*cols) for cols in df.values], index=df.index, name='column')
>>> pd.concat([s, df], axis=1)
          column  column_1 column_2
0  trial_84_test        84     test
1  trial_65_test        65     test
```

**Method 3**:  [Insert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) the new values at the first index of the dataframe (i.e. column 0).

```
df.insert(0, 'column', ['trial_{}_{}'.format(*cols) for cols in df.values])
>>> df
          column  column_1 column_2
0  trial_84_test        84     test
1  trial_65_test        65     test
```

**Method 3 (alternative way to create values for new column)**:

```
df.insert(0, 'column', df.astype(str).apply(lambda row: 'test_' + '_'.join(row), axis=1))
```

By the way, [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) is a keyword so you do not want to use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `lambda` for this, as it is just a thinly veiled loop. Here is a vectorised solution. Care needs to be taken to convert non-string values to `str` type.

```
df['column'] = 'trial_' + df['column_1'].astype(str) + '_' + df['column_2']

df = df.reindex_axis(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)  # sort columns alphabetically
```

Result:

```
          column  column_1 column_2
0  trial_84_test        84     test
1  trial_65_test        65     test
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I would give! Deserves the upvote and accept

Answer (score 0):

You can using `insert`

```
df.insert(0,column='Columns',value='trial_' + df['column_1'].astype(str)+ '_'+df['column_2'].astype(str)
)
df
Out[658]: 
         Columns  column_1 column_2
0  trial_84_test        84     test
1  trial_65_test        65     test
```